# Do monotouch bindings requires implement of the whole object hierarchy

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

Consider the following architecture taken from [PanoramaGL](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/):

```
@protocol PLIView <NSObject>
@end

@interface PLView : PLViewBase 
@end

@interface PLViewBase : UIView <PLIView, UIAccelerometerDelegate, PLTransitionDelegate> 
@end
```

My current monotouch binding looks like this:

```
[Model]
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
public partial interface PLIView {
}

[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
public partial interface PLViewBase : PLIView/*, UIAccelerometerDelegate, PLTransitionDelegate*/ {
}

[BaseType (typeof (PLViewBase))]
public partial interface PLView {
}
```

Notice that my *PLViewBase* class would need to implement two delegate implementation to follow the original code. However, I do not need access to the function provided by these delegates.

Is it correct to just comment them out like I did? If not, how can I make a correct binding with 2 base types?

Comment: What is the definition of PLIViewBase?

Comment: I presume you meant PLIView. I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient for the C# classes to map to the underlying Objective-C classes because it will provide the same idioms, but *technically*, it is not necessary.

As long as the methods can be invoked in a class "Foo", you can list all of the methods that you are interested in there.

So for strange class hierarchies, you can flatten in the way that would make the most sense in C#, and define the methods that you want in the places that you need them.

Comment: Good to know that a whole objective-c object's hierarchy can be flattened in a single binding class.